# Sharepoint 2013 Content Search Web Part Picture URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-search-web-part, picture

I have a Sharepoint site and a subsite attached as blog on an Enterprise Sharepoint.
I want to display the latest posts from this blog on the main page of the Sharepoint site. Therefor I make use of a Content Search Web Part which works pretty fine but no pictures are displayed at all.

[image: Result]

The settings are like shown below. I already have changed Picture URL to several other values but no picture is ever displayed at all. What would be the way to get pictures displayed either any random ones or ones which are within the post?

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change mapping of **Picture URL** Managed property to `BodyOWSMTXT` and then you will see picture inside Body container in post.

It will display first picture in Body container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new site column of type Picture
2. Add the site column to the Posts library.
3. Map the Picture URL to the newly created site column's managed property.

Hope this helps