# Unable to display image with description using content search webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have added content search webpart in my page to display content title,description with image like attached image but unable to display image with description.

[image]

not able to decide what is the setting required below screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting up the Picture URLs, you can do the following:-

By default the Picture URL property is configured to show the `PublishingImage;PictureURL;PictureThumbnailURL`.  Unless the results are publishing pages or images though, they probably won’t have an image specified for them.  So how do you change that?

You can actually add an existing column to any list or library on SharePoint that the CSWP will automatically display any image specified for.  Just go to the list or library, click on list/library settings, and under the Columns section click on Add from existing site columns.

1. Scroll down to the Rollup Image column, and Add it to the list or
   library.
2. You will now be able to specify an image for your list or library
   items.
3. In this example I specified Rollup Images for documents in my
   library.

You can also go through the below url's for more information:-

https://ootbtutorials.com/2016/10/09/content-search-web-part-cswp-setup/

[Sharepoint 2013 Content Search Web Part Picture URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139365/sharepoint-2013-content-search-web-part-picture-url)